# Cursor size and selection issue

Tags: mouse, cinnamon, cursor

Booted up to a weird issue.  My cursor size and selection change when I mouse over from desktop to browser.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXpj3.jpg
I didn't change anything in themes, nor mouse pointers and such.  I have tried changing the size and cursor back to DMZ-White but it didn't work.
Running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and Cinnamon 3.6.7.  Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this problem persistent? That is, what happens if you shutdown and restart your machine?

Comment: You haven't provided any details about your browser. I noticed it's Chromium from the screencast and I presume it's the snap version. In that case it's an unfortunate consequence of snap's restrictions. Does this answer your question? [Mouse cursor size is tiny in Chromium (Ubuntu 18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075872/mouse-cursor-size-is-tiny-in-chromium-ubuntu-18-04). Also see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1579268 and https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/use-the-system-gtk-theme/496

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Problem persists after reboot as well as a hard shutdown and restart.

Comment: @pomsky  My apologies!  Version 85.0.4183.83.  I don't see it in the snap list.  I will check out the links you sent.